# Integrating Flex 4.6 and Coldfusion

Tags: sql-server, apache-flex, coldfusion

I'm having some challenges with getting my Flex front-end form to pass its data into Coldfusion and subsequently SQL Server. Here is my code below:

```
MXML:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
     width="764" height="434"
     width.State1="630"  creationComplete="initApp()">
<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    s|Form#form1 s|FormItem
    {
        skinClass: ClassReference("spark.skins.spark.FormItemSkin");
    }
    s|Form#form1 s|FormHeading
    {
        skinClass: ClassReference("spark.skins.spark.FormHeadingSkin");
    }
    s|Form#form1
    {
        skinClass: ClassReference("spark.skins.spark.FormSkin");
    }
</fx:Style>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import assets.*;
        import assets.comps.accountManagement.userLogin;
        import assets.comps.accountManagement.userRegistration;
        import model.*;
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.events.ValidationResultEvent;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
        import mx.rpc.events.*;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
        import vo.*;

        //public var cfcResponse:String;
        //this gets called when the application is done being created
        //
        [Bindable]
        private function initApp():void{
            //this calls the confirmCFC method in remoting.cfc
            //cfc_ro.confirmCFC(); }
        //Result Event Method maps RO call to Result Event
        //public function loadConfirm(event:ResultEvent):void{
            //this binds the cfcResponse var to the result of the RO call
            //cfcResponse = event.result as String; 
        }


        //Method submits registration information to the DB via the controller Registration.cfc
        //Upon Successful registration, user receives a confirmation of their successful 
        registration.
        protected function createUser():void
        {
            userRegistrationRO.userRegMethod(
                fName.text, 
                lName.text, 
                uName.text, 
                password.text, 
                city.text,
                state.name,
                zip.text,
                email.text, 
                DOB.name,
                secQuestion1.name,
                secQuestion2.name, 
                ans1.text, 
                ans2.text);
        }
        //Method initiated on the Reset button click and clears form fields
        private function _resetForm():void 
        {
            fName.text = "";
            lName.text = "";
            uName.text = "";
            password.text = ""
            city.text = "";
            state.selectedIndex -1;
            email.text = "";
            confirm_email.text = "";

        }
        //Result event for registration 
        private function registrationResultEvent(event:ResultEvent):void{

        }
        //Fault handler for userRegMethod function
        private function registrationFaultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void{
            Alert.show("Your attempt to register was unsuccessful. Please try again. If problem  
          persists, contact Administrator")

        }
        //Registration RO Event Handler
        private function regROHandler(event):void{
            Alert.show("RO connection successful");
        }
        //Registration RO Fault Handler
        private function regROFaultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void{
            Alert.show("Error 100: Remote object call unsuccessful. Unable to submit data. Please  
        contact Administrator at support@blackiceems.com");
        }
        //variable references user registration popup
        private var userRegForm:userRegistration;

        //Registration Event Handler. Notifies user of successful registration by displaying a 
        confirmation message.       
        private function regHandler(event:Event):void
        { Alert.show("Registration Successful!");
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(userRegForm);  }
        //This funtion calls user reg. form 
        private function showRegForm():void {
            //This variable calls the Login Title Windows
            //var userRegForm:userRegistration = new userRegistration as IFlexDisplayObject =
            userRegForm = new userRegistration();
            userRegForm.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler);
            userRegForm.addEventListener("register", regHandler);
            userRegForm.addEventListener("cancel", closeHandler);
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(userRegForm, this, true);
            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(userRegForm);
            //userRegForm.setInitialFocus();
        }
        //Close Registration Event Handler  
        private function closeHandler(event):void
        {Alert.show("You cancelled the login operation", "Login Cancelled");
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(userRegForm);
        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

</s:RemoteObject>-->

```
<!--End of Transitions Code Block-->
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->     
    <!--This remote object passes form data from the form into the CFC DAO. Data Validates on client and server side.-->

    <!-- Defines the data model for the form. -->
    <!--<fx:Model id="formInfo">
        <formData>
            <date>
                <month>{monthInput.text}</month>
                <day>{dayInput.text}</day>
                <year>{yearInput.text}</year>
            </date>
            <name>
                <firstName>{fNameInput.text}</firstName>
                <lastName>{lNameInput.text}</lastName>
            </name>
            <phoneNum>{phoneInput.text}</phoneNum>
        </formData>
    </fx:Model>-->
    <!-- Define the validators. -->
    <mx:StringValidator id="fNameValidator" 
                        required="true"
                        source="{fName}" 
                        property="text"
                        minLength="3"
                        maxLength="10"
                        tooShortError="Your entry is too short to be a valid last name."
                        tooLongError="Your entry is too long to be a valid first name."/>
    <mx:StringValidator id="lNameValidator" 
                        required="true"
                        source="{lName}" 
                        property="text"
                        minLength="2"
                        maxLength="12"
                        tooShortError="Your entry is too short to be a valid last name."
                        tooLongError="Your entry is too long for a last name."/>
    <mx:StringValidator id="cityValidator" 
                        required="true" 
                        source="{city}" 
                        property="text"
                        minLength="4"
                        maxLength="15"
                        tooShortError="Your city name is too short to be valid"/>
    <mx:StringValidator id="stateValidator" 
                        required="true" 
                        source="{state}" 
                        property="text"/>
    <mx:ZipCodeValidator id="zipcodeValidator"
                         required="true"
                         source="{zip}"
                         property="text" />
    <mx:StringValidator id="emailValidator" 
                        required="true" 
                        source="{email}" 
                        property="text" 
                        tooLongError="Your email address exceeded the maximum length allowed."
                        tooShortError="Your email address is too short to be a valid email address."/>
    <mx:StringValidator id="confirm_emailValidator" 
                        required="true"
                        source="{confirm_email}" 
                        property="text"/>

    <mx:StringValidator id="userNameValidator" 
                        required="true" 
                        source="{uName}" 
                        property="text" 
                        minLength="6"
                        maxLength="15"
                        tooShortError="Your username must be a minimum of 6 alphanumeric characters."
                        tooLongError="Your username is too long. Usernames must not exceed 15 alphanumberic characters."/>

</fx:Declarations>
<!--Form Layout Elements and text fields contained below-->
<s:TitleWindow height="100%" close="PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);" controlBarVisible="true"
               title="New Member Registration"
               width.p2="100%"
               width.State1="100%">
    <s:controlBarContent>
        <s:Button label="Register"
                  click.p2="createUser();" enabled.p2="true"
                  click.State1="createUser();" enabled.State1="true"/>
        <s:Button label="Reset"
                  click.State1="_resetForm();showRegForm();"/>
    </s:controlBarContent>
    <s:layout.State1>
        <s:ConstraintLayout/>
    </s:layout.State1>
    <!--Form Starts Here-->
    <s:Form id="RegForm" width="100%" height="90%" skinClass="spark.skins.spark.FormSkin">
        <s:SkinnableContainer width="100%" height="350">
            <s:FormItem id="f_Name" includeIn="State1" label="First Name">
                <s:TextInput id="fName" width="100%" displayAsPassword="false" tabEnabled="true"
                             tabFocusEnabled="true" tabIndex="0"/>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem id="l_Name" includeIn="State1" x="230" label="Last Name">
                <s:TextInput id="lName" tabEnabled="true" tabFocusEnabled="true" tabIndex="1"/>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem id="frm_city" includeIn="State1" x="0" y="53" label="City">
                <s:TextInput id="city" tabIndex="2"/>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem id="frm_zip" includeIn="State1" x="371" y="59" width="165"
                        label="Zip Code">
                <s:TextInput id="zip" width="77"/>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem id="frm_state" includeIn="State1" x="206" y="55" width="157" height="41"
                        label="State">
                <s:DropDownList id="state" width="100" prompt="Select Date" selectedIndex="-1">
                <s:dataProvider>
                    <s:ArrayList>
                        <fx:String> Alabama</fx:String>
                        <fx:String> Alaska</fx:String>
                        <fx:String> California</fx:String>
                        <fx:String> Colorado</fx:String>
                        <fx:String> Conneticut</fx:String>
                    </s:ArrayList>
                </s:dataProvider>
                </s:DropDownList>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem id="frm_email" includeIn="State1" x="0" y="100" width="214" label="Email">
                <s:TextInput id="email" width="152"/>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem id="frm_cfirm_email" includeIn="State1" x="257" y="100" width="279"
                        label="Confirm Email">
                <s:TextInput id="confirm_email" width="152"/>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem id="frm_username" includeIn="State1" x="1" y="142" width="213"
                        label="Username">
                <s:TextInput id="uName"/>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem id="frm_password" includeIn="State1" x="3" y="191" width="215"
                        label="Password">
                <s:TextInput id="password" displayAsPassword="true"/>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:Button x="0" y="326" label="&gt;&gt; Next"
                      x.p2="0" y.p2="328" width.p2="96" label.p2="&lt;&lt; Previous"
                      click.p2="currentState='State1'"
                      x.State1="0" y.State1="328" click.State1="currentState='p2';initApp();"/>
            <s:FormItem includeIn="p2" x="1" y="10" width="644" label="Security  Question 1:">
                <s:DropDownList id="secQuestion1" width="409" mouseEnabled="false">
                    <s:dataProvider>
                            <s:ArrayList>
                                <fx:String> What was your high school mascot?</fx:String>
                                <fx:String> What is your mother's maiden Name?</fx:String>
                                <fx:String> What was your first car?</fx:String>
                            </s:ArrayList>
                        </s:dataProvider>
                </s:DropDownList>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem includeIn="p2" x="1" y="108" width="644" label="Security  Question 2:">
                <s:DropDownList id="secQuestion2" width="409" mouseEnabled="false">
                    <s:dataProvider>
                    <s:ArrayList>
                        <fx:String> Who was your best friend growing up? </fx:String>
                        <fx:String> What city were you born in? </fx:String>
                        <fx:String> What was your first car?</fx:String>
                    </s:ArrayList>
                    </s:dataProvider>
                    </s:DropDownList>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem includeIn="p2" x="64" y="58" width="254" label="Answer 1">
                <s:TextInput id="ans1" width="160"/>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem includeIn="p2" x="359" y="59" width="286" label="Confirm Answer">
                <s:TextInput width="160"/>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem includeIn="p2" x="64" y="159" width="254" label="Answer 1">
                <s:TextInput id="ans2" width="160"/>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem includeIn="p2" x="359" y="160" width="286" label="Confirm Answer">
                <s:TextInput width="160"/>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem id="frm_DOB" includeIn="State1" x="257" y="153" label="D.O.B.">
                <mx:DateChooser id="DOB" x="183" y="288" width="189" height="146"/>
            </s:FormItem>
            <!--This label displays value of cfcResponse variable when Front-end to CFC remote object call is successful-->
            <!--<s:Label includeIn="State1" x="0" y="240" width="171" height="40" color="#F6F309"
                     text="{cfcResponse}"/>-->
        </s:SkinnableContainer>
    </s:Form>
</s:TitleWindow>
```

```
   Coldfusion CFC:
```

```
<cffunction name="init" access="public" output="false" returntype="any">
        <cfargument name="DSN" required="true" type="string" hint="datasource" />
        <cfset variables.DSN = arguments.DSN />
        <cfreturn this />
</cffunction>
<!---Flex app CFC Remoting test function--->
<cffunction name="confirmCFC" access="remote" 
returntype="any" 
description="tests the remote object communication between View the controller code" >
<cfreturn "Your Flex Remoting with this CFC is successful."/>
</cffunction>
    <!---User Registraton--->
    <!---Function pulls form values from flex form via Remote Object Call--->
<cffunction name="userRegMethod" access="remote" output="false" returntype="any">
        <cfargument name="fName" type="string" >
        <cfargument name="lName" type="string">
        <cfargument name="uName" type="string" >
        <cfargument name="password" type="string">                  
        <cfargument name="city" type="string">
        <cfargument name="state" type="any" default="CA">
        <cfargument name="zip" type="string">
        <cfargument name="email" type="string">
        <cfargument name="dob" type="any" default="05/20/1982">
        <cfargument name="secQuestion1" type="any" default="Mother's maiden name">
        <cfargument name="secQuestion2" type="any" default="What's your high school mascot?">
        <cfargument name="ans1" type="string" default="Maxine">
        <cfargument name="ans2" type="string" default="Tigers">
        <!---Query Checks for Existing User In DB--->
                <cfquery name="qryUserExistence" datasource="blackiceDS">
                    select email,userName 
                    from tblUserAccount 
                    where email = <cfqueryparam value="#argument.email#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
                     OR uName = <cfqueryparam value="#argument.uName#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
                </cfquery>
                <!---If No User found by email, record count set to 0--->
        <cfif qryUserExistence.RecordCount eq 0 >

        <!---New User is then created in the table--->
                <cfquery name="qryCreateUser" datasource="BlackIceDS">
                    INSERT INTO  [dbo].tblUserAccount (fName,lName,uName,password, city, state, zip, email, dob,secQuestion1, secQuestion2, ans1, ans2)
                    VALUES (<cfqueryparam value="#fName#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
                    <cfqueryparam value="#lName#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
                    <cfqueryparam value="#uName#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
                    <cfqueryparam value="#password#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
                    <cfqueryparam value="#city#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
                    <cfqueryparam value="#state#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
                    <cfqueryparam value="#zip#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
                    <cfqueryparam value="#email#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
                    <cfqueryparam value="#dob#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
                    <cfqueryparam value="#secQuestion1#" cfsqltype="cf_sqlvarchar">,
                    <cfqueryparam value="#secQuestion2#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
                    <cfqueryparam value="#ans1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
                    <cfqueryparam value="#ans2#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">)       
                </cfquery>
    <!---Upon creation of new user account, user is returned a verification welcome message--->

        <cfelse>`enter code here`
<!---Otherwise if an existing account is discovered, user is informed of the    
 existing account and asked to select a different username and password--->
<cfreturn "An existing account was found with the selected username and/or           
password. Please select a different email address."/>
        </cfif>
</cffunction>
    <!---End of User Registraton Functions--->



    </cffunction>
```

My form has a date picker. How can I pass the selected date back to the CFC? When I try I get a Coldfusion error that the flex value is not of type date so I went to varchar as the value type and I still get an error. I'm trying to resolve this issue so my remote object call between Flex and CF verifies it works. I've included my preliminary code. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending the date from flex to Coldfusion as a String then define **dob** as a String in Coldfusion:

```
<cfargument name="dob" type="string">
```

When you call the remote function, I see you are passing `DOB.name`. Convert `DOB.selectedDate` to String. You can use `getDOBString(DOB.selectedDate)` 
You can define the function as below:

```
private function getDOBString(date:Date):String{
        var df:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
        df.formatString = "MM/DD/YYYY";
        var dateString:String = df.format(date);
        return dateString;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that pointer. I greatly appreciate the feedback. After changing the FaultEvent from the custom faultevent handler I created to the flex standard fault event handler, I'm getting an error that says my attempt to register a user failed because my argument EMAIL in the CFC is undefined. However, the value is defined in the flex form and I also set a default value for the email argument in the CFC. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Replace "#argument.email#" with "#arguments.email#"

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Its greatly appreciated.  Sometimes I get so visually stuck where everything looks the same and I miss the most simple yet obvious errors.